# PHP Search engine friendly urls and caching

Tags: php, caching, sef, prado

I'm considering ways to develop a site, planning to get some 100-10.000 visitors daily. (fingers crossed).

I used Prado framework for "backend" (admin access), but I'm not sure how well would Prado work on the visitors frontent. I have GoDaddy hosting and am not sure if things would work fast enough not to get lower google rating as a result of slow site loading.
(**If you guys think differently, please feel free to say so**).

However, if I'm not going to use Prado (and I'm too lazy to learn another framework for this project alone AND I don't have time right now), I'm having a problem with SEF urls and page caching.

I searched around for tutorials on the subject, but I noticed that most of them are old. So, could you guys propose some up-to-date tutorials, or verify that old tutorials are good tutorials :)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your too lazy to learn a different framework then how can you learn to use "SEF urls and page caching" without being able to integrate them properly?

Also you shouldn't be worried about your google ranking for a slow-loading website, you should be worried about how a slow-loading website will impact your user experience (which will result in a drop of traffic).

Anyways take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) it is a simple framework with everything you want and is relatively easy to learn.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i guess this is the 'if you guys think differently...' kind of answer :). still, i was hoping for smt different.